# An integral transform and the Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, semigroups-and-monoids

For a bounded function $\operatorname{F}: \mathbb{R}_{\,\ge\ 0} \to \mathbb{R}$ (*not necessarily non-negative*), if
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}\,s}{(s^{2} + x^{2})^{\left(k + 3\right)/2}\,\,}\, \operatorname{F}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x = 0\quad
\forall s > 0  
$$
where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is a positive constant,
is it true that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^{k}\,s}{(s^{2} + x^{2})^{\left(k + 3\right)/2}\,\,}\right)^{h} \, \operatorname{F}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x = 0\quad
\forall s > 0  
$$
where $h \in \mathbb{N}$?

This question is inspired by a comment to the answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996738/condition-for-an-integral-to-be-zero (which required to check the assumptions of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem).

More generally, ignoring the question above, my main concern is this:

- Use Stone-Weierstrass to prove that
  $$
  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}\,s}{(s^{2} + x^{2})^{\left(k + 3\right)/2}\,\,}\, \operatorname{F}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x = 0\quad
  \forall s > 0  
  $$
  if and only if $F \equiv 0$.

Comment: As argued in the thread you referred to, the first statement is true if and only $F$ is identically zero (almost everywhere). This means that the second statement is true as well.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig In the thread, the answer uses Stone-Weierstrass to show that the first statement is true if and only if $F$ is zero. But the proof is missing a step: you need to verify that the subalgebra generated by the expression in brakets satisfies that the integral is equal to zero, that is you need to verify the second statement

Comment: Is the first statement only supposed to hold for some $k$ which is independent of $s$, but not necessarily for every $k$, right?

Comment: @user49822 Correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1: There is a clear harmonic-analytic interpretation: if
\[ u(x, s) = C_k \int_{\mathbb R^{k+2}} \frac{s}{(s^2 + |x - y|^2)^{(k+3)/2}} \times |y|^{-1} F(|y|) dy , \]
then $u$ a harmonic function in the half-space $x \in \mathbb R^{k+2}$, $s > 0$, and $u(0, s) = 0$ for all $s > 0$. We claim that $u$ is identically zero, and hence $F = 0$ almost everywhere. This follows by standard tools: we have $\partial_s^n u(0, 1) = 0$ for all $n$, and so $\Delta_x^n u(0, 1) = 0$ for all $n$, and consequently all terms in the Taylor expansion of $u$ about $(0, 1)$ vanish.

---

Method 2 *(Edit: This is the same as Georgio Metafune's answer, which I did not realise in the beginning. Sorry!)* : Up to some powers of $s$, the integral is equal to the Mellin convolution of $F$ and the kernel
\[ x \mapsto \frac{x^k}{(1 + x^2)^{(k+3)/2}} . \]
The Mellin transform of that kernel is
\[ t \mapsto \frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{k-t}{2}) \Gamma(\tfrac{k+t}{2})}{2 \Gamma(k)} , \]
which has no zeros in the strip $0 \leqslant \Re t \leqslant k$. By the Mellin convolution theorem, we have $F = 0$.

The last step requires some care, since the Mellin transform of $F$ may fail to exist in the usual sense. One way around is to use distribution theory, as in Giorgio Metafune's answer. Another approach might be to split $F$ into two pieces ("small $x$" and "large $x$"), write the Mellin inversion formula for both of them, and deform the contour of integration.

Comment: I doubt this qualifies as "use Stone–Weierstrass to...", but might be of some interest anyway.

Comment: I prefer your method 1. By the way, the Mellin transform in method 2 should give the Fourier transform for $k$ even that I was unable to find.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: Ah, indeed — I only glanced at your answer and did not notice that in fact you were using the Mellin inversion formula in disguise. Sorry for that. Regarding the expression for the transform — I just used *Mathamatica*, but it is not the first time when I realise tables of Mellin transforms are more complete than tables of Fourier transforms.

Comment: No problem for me! Happy to discuss

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune and MateuszKwaśnicki: thanks to both of you for the interesting answers. Do you also have any idea about the approach using Stone-Weierstrass?

Comment: One never knows but I doubt. It Is a density property in $L^1$ rather than in spaces of continuous functions.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the assumption as
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{y^k}{(1+y^2)^\frac{k+3}{2}}F(sy) dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{(k+1)x}}{(1+e^{2x})^{\frac{k+3}{2}}}F(e^{t+x})dx=0.
$$
If $G(s)=F(e^s)$, this means that $G*v=0$, where $v(x)=\frac{e^{(k+1)x}}{(1+e^{2x})^{\frac{k+3}{2}}}$. Now $G$ is bounded and $v$ is in the Schwartz class  and we can take the Fourier transform of $G$ and of $G*v$ in the sense of tempered distributions obtaining $0=\hat G \hat v$, that is $\langle \hat G, \hat v \phi \rangle=0$ for every $\phi$ in the Schwartz class. Now the question is reduced to the existence of real zeros of $\hat v$. If $\hat v(a)=0$, with $a$ real, then $G(s)=e^{ias}$ satisfies $G*v=0$. On the other hand, if $\hat v$ never vanishes on $\mathbb R$, then $\hat v \phi=\psi$ can be solved for every $\psi \in C_c^\infty (\mathbb R)$ and $\langle \hat G, \psi \rangle=0$ for every $\psi \in C_c^\infty (\mathbb R)$ imples that the same is true for every $\psi$ in the Schwartz class, hence $\hat G=0$ and $G=0$, too.

Concerning the zeros of $\hat v$, I checked in the book of Erdely (Tables of integral transforms, I, formula 20 pag 120) and it turns out that there are no real zeros when $k$ is odd (formula (20) gives the Fourier transform when $(k+3)/2$ is an integer). I do not know for even integers but some more thoughts should give the answer.

Comment: Thanks! That's very interesting. What if we replace $\frac{x^{k}\,s}{(s^{2} + x^{2})^{\left(k + 3\right)/2}}$ by something more abstract but with the same scaling properties, like $s^{-\tfrac{k+2}{\alpha}} x^{k}  g(|x|s^{-(k+2)/\alpha})$ for a continuous function $g$ and a fixed $\alpha \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: It depends on the vanishing of the Fourier tranform or of the Mellin transform.